# How to replace a file to all user profiles on a network in c# using SCCM

Tags: c#, sccm

I want to copy an xml file from a server and then connect to all user profiles and overwrite the user profile xml file they have with the one copied from the server. I would like this to be an executable so it can be run with SCCM for all users. I know there will have to be administration privileges but I'm not certain how to code it. I'm also open to ideas as how to do this differently, but I do want to do this with C# and make it into an executable for SCCM.

```
   namespace copy_delete_move_files
{
    public class SimpleFileCopy
    {
        public static object Logger { get; private set; }

        static void Main()
        {
            string fileName = "Customize.xml";
            string sourcePath = @"\\pathToServer\c$\TestFolder";
            string targetPath = @"\\pathToUserProfiles\c$\%USERPROFILE%\APPDATA\Roaming\Folder\Customize";

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);       
            string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            // To copy a file to another location and 
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory.
            // Get the files in the source folder.
            // Note: Check for target path was performed previously
            // in this code example.

            if (Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }

            // Keep console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just realized that %USERPROFILE% creates a directory and all sub-directories and places in the final folder the copies of the file. I need it to get all users for all machines it connects to and ONLY replace the "Customize" folder and it's contents.

Comment: Ok so there is of course a way to query all user profiles with an executable with system rights but it is not always a good idea. As you execute this only once, every new profile that is created would not be affected. Also system needs read on your server. SCCM can also run a program once for every user that logs into the computer (now and also in the future) which makes the coding a lot easier (you can use %appdata% and don't have to take into consideration whether there are any form of roaming profiles active (although you maybe can just rule that out anyway)). Would that be ok in your case?

Comment: @Syberdoor That is exactly what I want. I want any user that logs on to have that xml file copied to their profiles at a specified path. It would create the "Customized" folder and place the xml file in it, overwriting any other that may be in there. How would I use the %appdata% in the code to drill down to the specified file path for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SCCM you can achieve this using the following steps:

1. Create your program in the way that it works for one user (the whole multi user part will be left to sccm you just write it in a way it works for any user you double click it with). As appdata path you just use something like:

   ```
   string fileNameWithExt = "your folderpath and filename";
   string destPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), fileNameWithExt);
   ```
2. In SCCM when you create your program in the wizard you select "Program can run: Only when a user is logged on" and "Run mode: Run with user's rights". Once created you enter the properties of the program go to "Advanced" and chose "When this program is assigned to a computer: Run once for every user that logs on"

This makes sure that not only all users now but all in the future will get the program. It also help you if you really want to copy from a server because by default SCCM uses the local system account which has no access rights to your server shares (although you could grant them). The should also be possible with an application instead of a program.

Downsides are:

- Your users ALL have to be allowed to access that share (could be
  bypassed by using sccms distribution point method but would be more
  complicated if the file on the server is updated often)
- If you need admin rights for any operations it is not possible this
  way. If the admin rights are only for parts that are not per user
  specific you could split the program into two parts one per machine,
  one per computer.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I need. I am still fairly new to programming, especially C#. Could you please explain a little better (Application.UserAppDataPath, fileNameWithExt)? I understand the "fileNameWithExt" and I believe the "UserAppDataPath" is the path to the specific user AppDataPath, but I'm not too clear on the "Application" part.

Comment: It's just a class with static methods (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application?view=netframework-4.7.2) that you can use to get the appdata folder. However I just copied it from one of my own examples and just saw that it is only useable in a winforms project so probably not ideal for you. You probably should use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) instead or something

Comment: Thank you for you assistance.